# React Native: Align Horizontally - Center and Right

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

In my React Native project, I need to align two elements. One should be in the centre and the other should be extreme right of the screen. However, I'm unable to get it right.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.mainTitle}>
        <Text style={{display: 'flex'}}>
          Main Title
        </Text>
        <Text
        style={{
          color: '#528bb4',
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight:600,
          marginLeft: 'auto',
          width:10,
          display:'flex',
          marginRight:10
        }}
      >?</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  mainTitle: {    display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff',height: '30%', width: '100%',alignItems: 'center',justifyContent: 'center',},
});
```

Snack URL: https://snack.expo.io/iXjlvlGpd

I'm unable to get the main element in center and the next element to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below, have am absolute position for the right Text and have alignself center for the text

```
  <View style={styles.mainTitle}>
    <Text style={{ display: 'flex', alignSelf: 'center' }}>Main Title</Text>
    <Text
      style={{
        color: '#528bb4',
        position: 'absolute',
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 600,
        right: 10,
        width: 10,
        display: 'flex',
        marginRight: 10,
      }}>
      ?
    </Text>
  </View>
```

https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/dfddf9

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the issue.

1. Basically remove the `display: 'flex'` since it is of no use.
2. Next, when you give `flex: 1` it makes the Text element take the remaining available width in it's parent.
3. Now that the element takes full width, give it `textAlign: 'center'` to make the text appear in the center.

```
<Text style={{ flex: 1, textAlign: 'center'}}>
   Main Title
</Text>
```

[Here is the snack](https://snack.expo.io/0Ybsp7CBB)

If you rather want to achieve true center, you would need to use absolutely position the right element so that the center element can take up the whole width. However this approach might cause overlap.

Comment: Thanks. This really helps. Is it possible to achieve true center for the main title, so that it's actually centred to the entire width, while still having the second element right aligned?

Comment: Hey. yes it is possible to achieve true center if we use position: 'absolute' on the right element. Updated the answer.